# Error reading project.json, Unterminated string error when performing dotnet restore

Tags: macos, asp.net-core

Using Visual Studio for Mac to perform a "dotnet restore" but the terminal shows this message:

```
error : Error reading
'/Users/abc/corefx/src/Microsoft.TargetingPack.Private.CoreCLR/ref/project.json' at line 8 column 1 : Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: ". Path 'frameworks', line 8, position 1.
error:Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: ". Path 'frameworks', line 8, position 1.
```

project.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.TargetingPack.Private.CoreCLR": "1.2.0-beta-24904-03"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1.0”: {}
  }
}
```

I have found the file but I cannot identify the cause of the problem. What could cause this error message?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the `netcoreapp1.1.0` property name is terminated with a typographic right quote mark `”` which is not valid JSON.  It should be a standard straight quote `"` instead.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.TargetingPack.Private.CoreCLR": "1.2.0-beta-24904-03"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1.0": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: I used you code but terminal show up error: Error reading '/Users/abc/coreclr/Tools/tool-runtime/project.json' at line 4 column 7 : Invalid character after parsing property name. Expected ':' but got: d. Path 'frameworks', line 4, position 7.
error:   Invalid character after parsing property name. Expected ':' but got: d. Path 'frameworks', line 4, position 7.

Comment: That's a different file than the one from your question.  Sounds like it has a similar problem.

Comment: hm.. I remove visual studio for Mac and reinstall app but target framework table have only dotnetcoreapp 1.0